# I having trouble assigning strings in an if else statement

Tags: java, string, conditional-statements

Right now I have a programming assignment to calculate bmi(body mass index) and assign it to a classificaiton.  Depending on the bmi it assigns it as follows.  I am having trouble with the classification getting the strings.  When i try to put the classification in a message box it tells me I do not have it initialized.

```
            public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Variables
    double bmi;         // Body Mass Index
    String weight;      // Weight in kilograms
    String height;      // height in meters
    String classification;

    weight = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Welcome to the BMI and BSA Calculator to begin enter weight in kilograms.");
    double weight2 = Double.parseDouble(weight);
    height = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter height in meters");
    double height2 = Double.parseDouble(height);

    bmi = weight2/(height2*height2);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your BMI is: " + bmi);

    if (bmi < 18.5)
    {
        classification = "Underweight";
    }
    else if (bmi < 25)
    {
        classification = "Normal";
    }
    else if (bmi < 30)
    {
        classification = "Overweight";
    }
    else
    {
        classification = "Obese";
    }


    JOptionPane.showInternalMessageDialog(null, "Your classification is: " + classification);
```

Comment: Do you define `classification` somewhere? `String classification;`

Comment: This should work, despite the parentheses around the string literals being redundant. Also, you might find issues with BMIs in the range [24.9, 25), as they are not covered in your ranges and will default to "Obese" (for example, note what happens if bmi = 24.95). Other than that, what @Felix said.

Comment: You need to show us how you declare classification. Also the enclosing () around the string literals aren't needed. You also have a spelling error in the dialog message.

Comment: Yes I have classification; right above my loop with my other variables also i fixed the range issues (teacher's handout not me) : )

Comment: @Brad: I'll repeat my comment from below: what loop? You don't show one in your code. Please edit your code to show us **all** of it.

Comment: @Mac sorry I posted the entire program now.  Also I may have worded my problem wrong.  The problem I'm having is that classification is not storing the literals I am assigning.

Comment: @Brad: no worries! Kudos for taking everyone's advice and implementing their suggestions. Unfortunately though, I still can't see any problems with the code. It looks like it should work to me...

Answer (score 2):

It's not really an answer to your question, but you're missing some values in your if statements. For example, what if bmi was 24.95, that wouldn't enter either the Normal or Overweight blocks.

In general, I try to pick one type of comparison, and just use that.

```
if (bmi < 18.5)
{
    classification = "Underweight";
}
else if (bmi < 25)
{
    classification = "Normal";
}
else if (bmi < 30)
{
    classification = "Overweight";
}
else
{
    classification = "Obese";
}
```

As for the error you're getting, assuming classification is declared just above the if statement, it really shouldn't be giving you that error.

Comment: sorry i have some >= and <= in there but they didn't copy over for some reasy

Comment: @Brad: I think you've missed the point. Look at your original code and work out what would happen for a BMI of 24.95.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Ah I get it sorry I'm really new to this this is my first programming class and if you haven't noticed I'm struggling a little. : )

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you change the last line to

```
String result = "Your result is: " + classification;        
JOptionPane.showInternalMessageDialog(null, result);
```

And why are you using showInternalMessageDialog instead of showMessageDialog as previously used.

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine, assuming you've declared the variable somewhere. (That's in terms of compiling and running without crashing; as pointed out in comments, the actual BMI comparisons have problems, and the brackets around the string literals are redundant.)

For example:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        double bmi = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);

        String classification;

        if (bmi < 18.5)
        {
            classification = ("Underweight");
        }
        else if (bmi >= 18.5  && bmi < 24.9)
        {
            classification = ("Normal");
        }
        else if (bmi >= 25 && bmi < 29.9)
        {
            classification = ("Overweight");
        }
        else
        {
            classification = ("Obese");
        }

        System.out.println("Classification: " + classification);
    }
}
```

Please show a similar short but complete program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Brad: which loop? You don't show one in your code. Showing us all of the code helps us to figure out these things - it looks like wherever the problem is in your code, it's not in what you've posted so far.

Answer (score -5):

To assign a variable String value do the following:

```
classification = new String("whatever");
```

Comment: No, there's no point in using the `new String(String)` constructor here.

Comment: @Asterisk: Yes, classification *is* a variable name... but why would you call a string constructor instead of just using the literal? And what do you think is wrong with the assignments in the code that's been given already?

Comment: @Jon I've never seen assignment using (). now I know that :)

Comment: What @Jon said. It's technically correct, but entirely redundant.

Comment: You're basically creating a String object using the "blah" syntax, and passing it into the copy constructor of String. Nice. Two objects with one stone.